# Dropdown menu not available in Api Management Developer Portal

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown, azure-api-management

I am unable to get a dropdown menu to work in the api management developer portal. There is very little documentation about this, but I have seen from github questions that it is suppose to be able to have a dropdown menu in the top menu bar like in [this link](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/136)

I am unable to get this myself. I have created pages in the navigation menu that have subpages,
and I tried to add a menu widget to the top bar with the root navigation item beeing the menu with subpages, but there is no options when editing the menu to select the list to be dropdown.

How can I get dropdown menues?

There are no "Submenu" or "Menu with Dropdown" widgets, the only other dropdown widgets I find is "List of APIs (dropdown)" and "List of products (dropdown)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the navigation structure you can create sub-menus by selecting a parent item and then clicking "Add navigation item" to add child items (also you can use arrow keys to make an existing item a subpage or promote it to parent level). After that, the Menu widget with "Horizontal" layout will display the dropdown when clicking on them. Menus with "Vertical" layout will form a tree of navigation items.